# the value from Tag of flextable blank

Tags: google-apps-script, flextable

I'm beginner in google apps script.
I wanna get value from Tag of flextable on the other function. i was initiate the Tag with setTag("init") on doGet() function before, but when i called getTag(), there's nothing (blank)
here's my code

```
var SPREADSHEET_ID = "xxx";

function doGet(){
  var app = UiApp.createApplication().setTitle('Request For Leaving');
  var panel = app.createVerticalPanel();
  var grid = app.createGrid(4, 4).setId('request');

  var employee = gsLibrary.getEmployee(SPREADSHEET_ID);

  var date1 = new Date();
  var preLabel = app.createLabel(': ').setText(': ');
  var preLabel2 = app.createLabel(': ').setText(': ');
  var preLabel3 = app.createLabel(': ').setText(': ');
  var preLabel4 = app.createLabel(': ').setText(': ');
  var preLabel5 = app.createLabel(': ').setText(': ');

  var employee = gsLibrary.getEmployee(SPREADSHEET_ID);
  var idLabel = app.createLabel('Employee ID ');
  var userIdLabel = app.createLabel(employee.employeeId).setId('userId').setTag(employee.employeeId);

  var yearLabel = app.createLabel('Year ');
  var yearDropdown = app.createListBox().setName("yearList").setId("yearList").setWidth('120px');

  var statusLabel = app.createLabel('Status ');
  var statusDropdown = app.createListBox().setName("statusList").setId("statusList").setWidth('120px');

  var searchButton = app.createButton("Search").setId("search");

  grid.setWidget(0, 0, idLabel)
    .setWidget(0, 1, preLabel5)
    .setWidget(0, 2, userIdLabel)
    .setWidget(1, 0, yearLabel)
    .setWidget(1, 1, preLabel4)
    .setWidget(1, 2, yearDropdown)
    .setWidget(1, 3, searchButton)
    .setWidget(2, 0, statusLabel)
    .setWidget(2, 1, preLabel3)
    .setWidget(2, 2, statusDropdown);

 var flexTable = app.createFlexTable()     
     .setId('myTable')
     .setTag('init')
     .setStyleAttribute('border','1px solid black')
     .setStyleAttribute("left","50px")
     .setStyleAttribute('borderCollapse','collapse')
     .setBorderWidth(1)
     .insertRow(0)
     .insertCell(0, 0).setStyleAttribute(0,0,"width","20px")
     .insertCell(0, 1).setStyleAttribute(0,1,"width","80px")
     .insertCell(0, 2).setStyleAttribute(0,2,"width","70px")
     .insertCell(0, 3).setStyleAttribute(0,3,"width","70px")
     .insertCell(0, 4).setStyleAttribute(0,4,"width","500px")
     .insertCell(0, 5).setStyleAttribute(0,5,"width","50px")
     .setText(0,0,'No. ')
     .setText(0, 1,'Leave Day(s)')
     .setText(0, 2,'Start Date')
     .setText(0, 3,'End Date')
     .setText(0, 4,'Description')
     .setText(0, 5,'Status')
     .setStyleAttribute('text-align','center').setCellPadding(10).setVisible(true);

  var searchHandler = app.createServerClickHandler('searchRequestList');   
  searchHandler.addCallbackElement(panel);   
  searchButton.addClickHandler(searchHandler);  
  setYearList(app,employee);
  setStatusList(app);

  panel.add(grid);
  panel.add(flexTable);
  app.setStyleAttribute("height","auto");
  app.add(panel);
  return app;
}

function setYearList(app,employee){
  var yearList = app.getElementById("yearList");
  var listYear=getAllYear(employee);
  var index=0;
  yearList.addItem("All Year");
  for (var i=0;i<listYear.length;i++){
    yearList.addItem(listYear[i]);
    index++;
  }

}

function getAllYear(user){
  var AllLeaveObjects = gsLibrary.getAllLeaveRequestByUser(SPREADSHEET_ID, user);
  var m_yearList=[];
  for (var i =0 ;i<AllLeaveObjects.length;i++){
   var status=true;
   var index;
   index=0;
    while (status==true && index<=m_yearList.length){
      if (gsLibrary.getYear(AllLeaveObjects[i].startDate)==m_yearList[index]){
        status =false;
     }
      index++;       
   }
    if (status==true){
      m_yearList.push(gsLibrary.getYear(AllLeaveObjects[i].startDate));

    }

  }

  m_yearList.sort();
  return m_yearList;
}

function setStatusList(app){
 var statusList = app.getElementById("statusList");
  var allStatus=getAllStatusName();
   statusList.addItem("All Status");
  for (var i=0;i<allStatus.length;i++){
    statusList.addItem(allStatus[i].status);
  }
}

function getAllStatusName(){
  var spreadsheetId = SPREADSHEET_ID;
  var sheet  = SpreadsheetApp.openById(spreadsheetId).getSheetByName("Status Request");
  var status = gsLibrary.getRowsData(sheet);  
  return status;
}

function getStatusNameByNum(num){
  var statusName;

  var allStatusName = getAllStatusName();
  for (var i =0 ;i<allStatusName.length;i++){
    if (num == allStatusName[i].statusCode){
      statusName = allStatusName[i].status;
    }
  }
  return statusName;
}

function searchRequestList(e){
    var app = UiApp.getActiveApplication();
    var employee = gsLibrary.getEmployee(SPREADSHEET_ID);
    var year=e.parameter.yearList;
    var status = e.parameter.statusList;

    fillTable(app,employee,year,status);
    return app;
}

function fill(table, LeaveRequest, index, row, tag){
  table.setText(index+1,0,index+1);
  table.setText(index+1,1,LeaveRequest[row].numberOfDays);
  table.setText(index+1,2,gsLibrary.convertDate(LeaveRequest[row].startDate));
  table.setText(index+1,3,gsLibrary.convertDate(LeaveRequest[row].endDate));
  table.setText(index+1,4,table.getTag()); //<--- this is the problem, always blank
  table.setText(index+1,5,getStatusNameByNum(LeaveRequest[row].status));
}

function setTagTable(){
  var app = UiApp.getActiveApplication();
  var table = app.getElementById("myTable");
  if(table.getTag() == 'init'){
    table.setTag() = '1';
  }
}

function fillTable(app,employee, year, status){
  setTagTable();
  var table =app.getElementById("myTable");
  var label = app.getElementById("showLabel");
  var LeaveRequest = gsLibrary.getAllLeaveRequestByUser(SPREADSHEET_ID, employee);
  var index = 0;


  if(year == "All Year" && status == "All Status"){
      for (var row = 0; row<LeaveRequest.length; row++){
        fill(table, LeaveRequest, index, row, ntag);
        index++;        
      }
  }
  else if(year == "All Year"){
      for (var row = 0; row<LeaveRequest.length; row++){
        if(getStatusNameByNum(LeaveRequest[row].status) == status){
          fill(table, LeaveRequest, index, row, ntag);
          index++;          
        }
      }
  }
  else if(status == "All Status"){
      for (var row = 0; row<LeaveRequest.length; row++){
        if(gsLibrary.getYear(LeaveRequest[row].startDate) == year){
          fill(table, LeaveRequest, index, row, ntag);
          index++;          
        }
      }
  }
  else {
      for (var row = 0; row<LeaveRequest.length; row++){
        if(gsLibrary.getYear(LeaveRequest[row].startDate) == year && getStatusNameByNum(LeaveRequest[row].status) == status){
          fill(table, LeaveRequest, index, row, ntag);
          index++;          
        }
      }
  }
}
```

gsLibrary is the library that i created before, there's no problem with it...
thank you :D

Answer (score 0):

You can get the tag of any widget in the fashion given below

```
function doGet(){
  ...
  var lbl = app.createLabel('Hello World').setId('lbl').setTag('tag'); 
  ...
}

function handleFunction(e){
  /* Some handler function invoked when a button is clicked etc. */
  var tag = e.parameter.lbl_tag; 
}
```

Comment: yeah...but can i get the value of tag without handler?

Comment: No, you can only get the value from within a handler or within doPost().